# Isomorphisms between Orderings

Tags: set-theory

If $h$ is an isomorphism between $(P,<)$ and $(Q,\prec)$ then show $h^{-1}$ is an isomorphism between $(Q,\prec)$ and $(P,<)$

DEFINITION: $h$ is an isomorphism between $(P,<)$ and $(Q,\prec)$ then $h(p_{1}) \prec h(p_{2})$ whenever $p_{1}<p_{2}$.
* I have this definition from definition 5.17 of Hrbacek and Jech.

how do I go about the inverse function?

This is what I have so far:

consider $p_{1}$ and $p_{2} \in P$ such that $p_{1} < p_{2}$

then we know by definition of $h$ that $h(p_{1}) \prec h(p_{2})$

can I conclude from there that $h^{-1}(h(p_{1})) < h^{-1}(h(p_{2}))$ ?

let $h(p_{1})=q_{1}$ and $h(p_{2})=q_{2}$ where $q_{1} , q_{2} \in Q$

then $h^{-1}(h(p_{1}))=h^{-1}(q_{1})$  and $h^{-1}(h(p_{2}))=h^{-1}(q_{2})$

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: In order to show that $h^{-1}$ satisfies the definition of an isomorphism from $\langle Q,\prec\rangle$ to $\langle P,<\rangle$, you must show that $h^{-1}(q_1)<h^{-1}(q_2)$ if and only if (**not** just *whenever*) $q_1\prec q_2$. Thus, you should be starting with arbitrary $q_1,q_2\in Q$ such that $q_1\prec q_2$, **not** with elements of $P$.

Suppose that $q_1,q_2\in Q$ and $q_1\prec q_2$. Since $h$ is an isomorphism, there are $p_1,p_2\in P$ such that $h(p_1)=q_1$ and $h(p_2)=q_2$; why? Clearly $p_1=h^{-1}(q_1)$ and $p_2=h^{-1}(q_2)$.

Now, knowing that $q_1\prec q_2$, what can you say about the relative order of $p_1$ and $p_2$ in $P$? Is it possible that $p_1=p_2$? Why? Is it possible that $p_2<p_1$? Why? And finally, is it possible that $p_1$ and $p_2$ are not comparable? Why? (All of those *Why?* questions have essentially the same answer.)

Comment: I'm failing to see why $p_1$ and $p_2$ are comparable.

Comment: @GitGud: For the same reason that the other situations in the last paragraph are impossible. (Sarah didn’t state the definition quite correctly.)

Comment: Ah! Thanks.${}{}$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott if $p_{1} = p_{2}$ then $h(p_{1})=h(p_{2})$ IE $q_{1}=q_{2}$ which is a contradiction.  Also if $p_{2}>p_{2}$ then $q_{2} \prec q_{1}$ which is also a contradiction.  Therefore we must have $p_{1} <p_{2}$ right?

Comment: @sarah: Basically, yes. There’s just one more step: if $p_1$ and $p_2$ are not comparable, then $q_1$ and $q_2$ are not comparable (because of the *if and only if* in the definition of $h$ being an isomorphism), which is also a contradiction.